# Send method call via object instance method OR loop in main activity to check if boolean is true in object instance method

Tags: java, android, performance

tldr: I'm wondering if it's better to send a call to an activity to start a method or if it's better to loop in the activity to see if the object method has been triggered.

Description:
I'm creating a timer which is triggered by sound in android studio. I've created a separate class from my timerActivity, called percussionDetector. Using the library TarsosDSP and it's integrated functions. The question I'm having is if it's more appropriate to call the method to start the clock in the activity from the percussionDetector or if it's better to loop and check if the value becomes true in the the activity?

here's some pseudo-code to better describe my question:

```
//is this the best way to go? (MainActivity)
while(percussionDetector.onSetTriggered())
{
    if(timer!=null){
       stopTimer();
    }else{
       startTimer();
    }
}

//or this? (Object class)
public void onSetTriggered(){
    if(timer!=null){
       Activity.stopTimer();
    }else{
       Activity.startTimer();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help beforehand!

Comment: Maybe Observer pattern match in your code: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm

Comment: dont use forever loop. It's bad practice.  you could use `broadcast`, listener/interface instead.

Comment: thanks for the response guys! I'll be looking into both broadcasts and reciever patterns :)